# Função String.split() com separador contendo colchetes e asterisco

Tags: java, string, regex

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
String teste = "meta[[*]]etapa[[*]]especif[[*]]unid[[*]]qtd[[*]]01/01/2000[[*]]02/02/2000[[**]]";
String[] split = teste.split("[[*]]");
for (String string : split) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Não consigo entender porque o retorno está vindo da seguinte forma:

```
meta[[
]]etapa[[
]]especif[[
]]unid[[
]]qtd[[
]]01/01/2000[[
]]02/02/2000[[

]]
```

Comment: Você queria interpretar o ```[[*]]``` de forma literal? Quebrar com base nele e que ele fosse totalmente removido?

Comment: Queria montar uma lista de String baseado neste campo separador **[[*]]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O [método `split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) recebe como parâmetro uma expressão regular ([regex](/questions/tagged/regex)).

E [alguns caracteres possuem significado especial em regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special). Os colchetes criam uma [classe de caracteres](https://regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), e o asterisco é um [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) (significa "zero ou mais ocorrências").

Para que esses caracteres "percam seus poderes" e sejam interpretados como caracteres comuns, sem nenhum significado especial, você deve escapá-los com `\`. Mas como a regex é passada dentro de uma `String`, ela deve ser escrita como `\\`. Ou seja, o `[` deve ser escrito como `\\[`, e o mesmo vale para o `*` e o `]`. Então ficaria assim:

```
String[] split = teste.split("\\[\\[\\*\\]\\]");
```

Fazendo dessa forma, a saída é:

```
meta
etapa
especif
unid
qtd
01/01/2000
02/02/2000[[**]]
```

---

Não ficou claro se o `[[**]]` também é um separador. Caso seja, basta trocar para:

```
String[] split = teste.split("\\[\\[\\*{1,2}\\]\\]");
```

O [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{1,2}` significa "no mínimo 1, no máximo 2". E como ele está logo depois do asterisco, isso quer dizer que a regex aceita tanto um quanto dois asteriscos. Portanto o `split` considerará 1 ou 2 asteriscos para fazer a quebra da `String`. A saída passa a ser:

```
meta
etapa
especif
unid
qtd
01/01/2000
02/02/2000
```

---

Só pra constar, a sua regex estava pegando apenas o asterisco. Isso porque dentro de uma classe de caracteres (dentro dos colchetes), o asterisco não precisa ser escapado com `\`.

E [segundo a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes), é possível ter uma classe de caracteres dentro de outra. Por exemplo, `[a[b]]` é o mesmo que `[ab]`. Sendo assim, `[[*]]` acaba sendo o mesmo que `[*]`, que é uma classe de caracteres que só possui o `*`. Ou seja, esta regex pega apenas o asterisco.

Para saber o que uma regex pega, você pode fazer esse teste:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

...
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[[*]]").matcher(teste);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

No seu caso, verá que o código imprime vários asteriscos. Por isso o `split` fazia a quebra apenas nos asteriscos e não eliminava os colchetes.

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o que é esperado dentro do split() é um regex, então é necessário utilizar um escape, e o seu código ficará assim:

```
       String[] split = teste.split("\\[\\[\\*{1,2}\\]\\]");
```